# Can we import the product images from live server using magmi or magento's product import functionality?

Tags: magento, magmi

My all Images are stored in live site. Can We import these all images from live site(mapped by image name in .csv file.) to my current site using magmi or magento's product import functionality?
Like mentioned in below image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use magmi to import images by specifying full image path in csv file.You need to enable `Image attributes processor` plugin in magmi.Detailed documentation about image import is [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor)